# Access Tokens - Extending - Error

Tags: facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I am using a desktop application.

I am able to successfully obtain a short-term token.

I am able to convert the short-term token to a long term token, which will expire in 60 days.

What I am assuming is the access-token-extend process, will extend the life of the token another 60 days, without the user needing to login.  (If the user does not use the desktop application for 60 days - it will expire, and they will need to login to get the new token).

I would like to run the access-token-extend process each time the application is launched, thereby keeping the token continually alive if the user operates the application on a regular basis (daily).

Based on the following link to obtain my "how to"
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending
 (refer to section "Getting the Code")

I am using the following url:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=....&client_secret=....&redirect_uri=....&client_id=.....

The response is:
{
     "error": {
        "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
        "type": "OauthException",
        "code": 1
     }
}
The above error message is return when all the uri query elements are correct.

If any are purposely changed to be incorrect, I get the appropriate error.  Eg. "this is a short term token, require long-term", or "redirect uri is incorrect".

I have made a few changes in the Facebook App Settings, Basic and Advance without any success.

Can anyone see what I might be missing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just go through the same process you went through to initially get the short-term token and convert it to a new longer lived 60 day token, it will return you a new token that lives for 60 days from the request. If the user has not revoked access to your app or the old token has not yet expired, the user will not have to go through the oauth acceptance in facebook again. One thing you should note, using this method if the user is not already logged in, it will prompt the user to log in to facebook before returning the token.